# Android Studio Hola CDN onAttach method not working for ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1, exoplayer

I have integrated Hola CDN in my android app & when I am trying to attach my ExoPlayer after connection established with Hola CDN by doing this-

```
 if(api.is_connected())
              api.attach(player.get_player(), userAgent, new TransferListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onTransferStart() {
                      System.out.print("start");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onBytesTransferred(int i) {
                      System.out.print("start byte");

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onTransferEnd() {
                      System.out.print("start end");

                  }
              }, videoUrl);
```

,It gives this error -

> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
>
> com.google.android.exoplayer.util.Assertions.checkNotEmpty(Assertions.java:122)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding & references. Getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` means passing undesired param. In your case, `Assertions.checkNotEmpty()`method needs **NON EMPTY String**. But, getting **NULL String** due to something [that you need to trace out] & that's the reason your are getting above exception.

Giving you the below description,

> checkNotEmpty(String string) Throws IllegalArgumentException if string
>
> is null or zero length.

on

1]https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/util/Assertions.html

2]https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/util/Assertions.html#checkNotEmpty-java.lang.String-

If you fix this then rest of the things might work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was coming due to some other reason but now i have solved it.Now came to face another error when I am attaching my player to hola it gives this-

Comment: hola skip http://watchlive.webcam/explorika/cafe1.stream/playlist.m3u8 (origin is not allowed)

Comment: Mean this time my video will not play by hola it will play my existing player.

Comment: Ask separate questions.

Comment: @VVbB i am done with it by changing "zone" value which i was sending to hola server.